# Cannot visit some pages in browser

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter, ssl-certificate, wifi-configuration

I have just installed my new network adapter for wireless connectivity. I am using TP-LINK TL-WN727N. I installed the drivers from the manufacturers website to get the latest version. The installation worked well but I still have problems with visiting other pages.

Using internet explorer, I cannot visit some pages including google.com. It says there is a certificate error, but when I click "continue to this website(not recomended)", it will then proceed. It shows something like this:

[image]

I downloaded google chrome and tried to do the same, visit google.com. It says that it cannot connect to the real www.google.com. Image is something like this

[image]

Some things I noticed:

- When I hover on the wifi symbol (the one on the taskbar on the right end), it says "Identifying... Internet Access". I wonder why is this so. Normally it should say "<Router Name> Internet Access"
- I opened network and sharing center but my computer seems to be not connected to the internet but still I can visit some pages. How can I fix this? Refer to image below:
  [image]

I am not sure of what the problem is here. I reinstalled the network adapter's drivers and I can visit some pages but not all. Both browsers say that there is a certificate error or an SSL error, and to add to that, hovering on the wifi symbol says "Identifying... Internet Access". I am pretty sure I am not being hacked because I am using a home network.

-- Update: Some ipconfig results --

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection *2:
 Media State: Media Disconnected
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix:
 
 Wireless LAN Adapter Wi-Fi:
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix: domain.name

ping statistics are normal.

-- **Some of the things I already tried** --

- Change system time to sync with the internet. I synced my time with server time.windows.com
- Forget my home and reconnect
- Disconnect from wifi then reconnect
- reinstall network adapter's driver
- cleared browser cache etc. (ctrl+shift+del)
- reinstalled chrome

Please help me, No solution to my problem until now. I'll follow any suggestion you make.

**--- Update: Already fixed some stuff but still has certificate error on both browsers ---**
I fixed the problem on network and sharing center. Now it displays my network. I edited the permissions under the registry key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList

Still, I cannot visit some pages using both iexplorer and chrome.

Comment: May be you need to change IP address to DHCP or to static. Not sure. Give it a try.

Comment: Check your system time and include a screenshot of the page.

Comment: I already changed the system time to sync with the internet

Comment: @Danatela I don't know how to do that can you elaborate?

Comment: @krato Ok but can you include a screenshot? Make sure to hit "Show extra info" if you can.

Comment: @chipperyman573 I cannot visit superuser on that computer, so I am using a different one. Will try to search on google images for similar pics

Comment: Your network adapter settings -> Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) Properties -> Get the IP address automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your IP to dynamic. To do this:

1. Open Network Connections.

   [image: ![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge0Qf.jpg)]
2. Select Your Adapter, right-click and select Properties (or just <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)
3. Select Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IP)

   [image: ![](http://emedia.leeward.hawaii.edu/itg/sites/default/files/w7setupDHCP3.png)]
4. Select Automatic IP Configuration

   [image]

Refer to [this guide](http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/GetArticle.aspx?docid=30876a76bd944c51b26463cb077b6cf3_4033.xml&pid=80&converted=0) if you have problems.

Comment: I already did this. Still cannot view the pages. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

- Try pinging problematic sites.

  - Goto the start menu, type `cmd.exe` and hit enter.
  - Type `ping <website URL here>` and hit enter
  - Tell us what you see
- Type `ipconfig` in another `cmd.exe` window. Tell us what you see.

That should get us some useful info to work with.

--------- Update 1 ----------

Now try resetting your browser cache in IE and Chrome. See if that fixes it.

Comment: Hi, what in particular in ipconfig do you want to see?

Comment: I pinged www.google.com it replied for the 4 instances

Comment: Anything to do with `Wireless LAN`. Or WiFi in general. (My own is polluted with Ethernet adapters and such). Your ping results are good. I'll have to think about how to continue debugging. See updated answer.

Comment: is that ctrl+shift+delete then delete everything?